# How can I strip symbols from my iOS framework?

Tags: ios-frameworks

I have built an iOS framework (release) but when I 'nm'/'otool' it, I see symbols I don't want to be exposed. And that are local symbols (no need to have them exported).

As an example:
I extract the arm64 part using lipo.
And I see what symbols are exported in the binary using "nm -G myLibrary".
I get a lot of:
_kMyLibraryPrivateKey
_MyLibrarySecretThing

I tried to use "strip -x MyLibrary -o MyLibraryStripped", I get no error but the binary is still the same size and I get the same result with the 'nm' command.

Why is not doing anything? how can I remove all these symbols from my framework and only keep the one that are needed by apps using it?

Any help welcome!! Thanks!

Comment: I know this may be a little bit an expert field, but I'm very concerned with what can be seen from my framework... I also tried out nmedit with no success

Comment: Sounds like I could use 'ld' too but it is hard to find any example

Answer (score 1):

ok, so I finally found out how to:
 1. separate every part of the binary (arm, x86)
 2. 'strip -ur' them
 3. merge them back together

And voilà!

Comment: I guess you mean on (1) to strip the fat binary to its architectures, but what do you mean in (2) ?